# New to iOS Dev with oDesk Contractors - How receive the finished app?

Tags: ios, udid

I am new to the iOS world and feeling my way thru the processes.
I have a contractor developing an app thru oDesk. The contractor has the app to working stage its time to test - he is asking for my dev login info and UDID so he can create the certificate and allow me to test without actually handing over the code. Is this a good idea? Am I breaking rules or is it just not smart?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure why he would need your dev login info (are you referring to your Apple developer login info?), and I would be very reluctant to do so in most cases. A more typical approach is to use testflightapp.com to distribute beta/test versions.

Answer (score 1):

What he's doing is creating an adhoc build, which cannot be published to the App Store, but can be used to install directly to the associated phone.

He needs the login to create an ad hoc certificate which links devices to the associated build, if there's no UDID linking on an adhoc certificate its impossible for you to use the app without building the app yourself.

You can create a separate user for your developer which has rights to distribute and create adhoc accounts so he doesn't touch your financial section in iTunes Connect.

To do so:

1. Go to itunesconnect.apple.com
2. Enter your username and password
3. Manage Users
4. Create a user a Technical Role

[image: iTunes Connect user roles]

Comment: So i create the additional login thru itunes connect only, he doesnt need my main login to create the adhoc certificate?

Comment: What he needs is Technical to create the certificates and sales to distribute the final product. Admin encompases everything iirc and Legal is your financial contracts and bank linking.

Comment: And would something like Testflight be better? Like Bobnoble suggested?

Comment: Test flight requires you to go through the same process, the only difference is that it links your UDID and emails together and you upload the build to Test Flight so others can download from Test Flight. You still require to create an ad hoc build which requires the certificates to be created. Sorry if this is confusing to you. If you think its confusing to non-programmers, its still confusing to many programmers. Just I've been through this song and dance many times.

Comment: Gotcha, Awesome. Thank you so much for the quick answers! I will try to create the iTunes Connect login and go that route.

Comment: Sorry, I need to make an amendment, Sales is not required for your programmer, just Technical. I'll post a screenshot of the roles.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct when you've succeeded.